# How to receive mouse clicks in a NSTableCellView subclass?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have subclassed `NSTableCellView` to do some custom drawing.  When the containing `NSOutlineView`'s highlight style is set to **None** my view receives mouseDown events.
When I change the `NSOutlineView`'s highlight style to **Regular**, my view no longer receives its mouseDown events.

How can I pass the mouseDown events to my view while keeping the outline view's highlight style to Regular?

Comment: Any subviews in the NSTableCellView or are you watching out for clicks directly going to that view?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently `NSTableView` overrides `-hitTest:` in order to implement the row selection/dragging/etc. functionality - that would explain why you're having no issues when the highlighting style is **None**.

As per the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/RowSelection/RowSelection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH6-SW9):

> **Specifying How Subviews Should Respond to Events**
>
> [...] If you create a table view subclass, you can override validateProposedFirstResponder:forEvent: to specify which views can become the first responder. In this way, **you receive mouse events**.

Or optionally.. if event handling is vital to your subclass: Why not create a `NSControl` subclass?
As per the same docs there's special handling for controls already implemented in the stock table view class.

Comment: That's it.  In my outline view subclass, I override validateProposedFirstResponder:forEvent: to return YES when responder is my NSTableCellView subclass.  Thank you very much.